# Need basic help parsing a string in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

C++ is not my preferred language.

I have a file that contains this:

```
e 225,370 35,75
```

I want to separate e, 225, 370, 35 and 75 from each other into a char and ints but I'm having trouble.  I tried doing everything I found online and in my C++ book and still it's not working out. Please help.

I would have an easier time doing this in Java.

Comment: Thanks guys. C++ is very frustrating to me sometimes as I learned Java first.

Comment: Though it sometimes can be frustrating it helps to get a hold of some powerful libraries that aren't always bundled directly like they are with Java. Imagine how frustrating Java would be if all you had was the core language and no libraries.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        ifstream f("a.txt"); // check for errors.

        char ch,dummy;
        int i1,i2,i3,i4;

        f>>ch>>i1>>dummy>>i2>>i3>>dummy>>i4;

        cout<<ch<<endl<<i1<<endl<<i2<<endl<<i3<<endl<<i4<<endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The [C++ String Toolkit Library (StrTk)](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html) has the following solution to your problem:

```
int main()
{ 
   std::string data("e 225,370 35,75");
   char c1;
   int i1,i2,i3,i4;
   strtk::parse(data,", ",c1,i1,i2,i3,i4);
   return 0;
}
```

More examples can be found [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Tokenizer.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

If you have control over the format, it'll be (slightly) easier to read if you eliminate the commas, and just have input like

> e 225 370 35 75

With this format, Poita_'s code for reading the data will work [edit: he's since update his code to explicitly read and skip the commas]. Otherwise, you'll need to explicitly skip over the commas:

```
char ingore1, ignore2;
char ch;
int i[4];

file >> ch >> i[0] >> ignore1 >> i[1] >> i[2] >> ignore2 >> i[3];
```

[Edit: if you're paranoid or really need to verify your input, at this point you can check that `ignore1` and `ignore2` contain commas.]

In most cases, however, the data are probably related, so you'll want to read an entire line into a single struct (or class):

```
struct data { 
    char ch;
    int i[4];

    std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, data &d) { 
        char ignore1, ignore2;
        return is >> ch >> i[0] >> ignore1 >> i[1] >> i[2] >> ignore2 >> i[3];
    }
};
```

Having done this, you can read an entire `data` object at a time:

```
std::ifstream infile("my data file.txt");
data d;

infile >> d;
```

Or, if you have a whole file full of these, you can read them all into a vector:

```
std::vector<data> d;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<data>(infile), 
    std::istream_iterator<data>(),
    std::back_inserter(d));
```

Comment: Nice one. I'm usually messing with string's find and substr methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the old fashioned C runtime

```
FILE * pf = fopen(filename, "r");
char e;
int  a, b, c, d;
int ii = fscanf(pf, "%c %d,%d %d,%d", &e, &a, &b, &c, &d);
if (ii < 5) 
   printf("problem in the input file");
fclose (pf);
```

edit: added error checking based on comment from **dreamlax**

Comment: This one is very clean-looking. Although, be sure to check that the return value of `fscanf` is 5 to ensure that all variables were assigned appropriately.

Comment: In these situations I believe fscanf to be superior to the C++ ways.

Comment: What is up with all of the drive by markdowns on this answer? current score is +4 -3, and not a single markdown willing to explain why.

Comment: I think it may be because the answer is more `C` than `C++`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've read the data into a strings ...

1. strchr is like String.index.
2. strtol is like Integer.parseInt()

What else do you need?

Comment: strtok would be more convenient than strchr

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <fstream>

/* ... */

ifstream file;
file.open("yourfile.txt");
char c, dummy;
int i[4];
file >> c >> i[0] >> dummy >> i[1] >> i[2] >> dummy >> i[3];
file.close();
```

Comment: I'm not certain of the behavior, as I'm not a C++ programmer, but I would be surprised if this just ignored the commas in the file.  Does it?

Comment: @danben:it can, but by default it won't. Even most dedicated C++ programmers never touch the parts of the library necessary to get it to ignore the commas (you have to create a custom `ctype facet`, create a `locale` containing that `facet`, then `imbue` the stream with that `locale`).

Answer (score 2):

Use Boost Tokenizer to split the string.  I am assuming that only the first token is a char, so sample code would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

...

typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;

string teststring("e 225,370 35,75");
boost::char_separator<char> separators(", ");
tokenizer tokens(teststring, separators);
vector<string> substrings;
for (tokenizer::iterator iter = tokens.begin(); iter != tokens.end(); ++iter)
{
    substrings.push_back(*iter);
}
```

and, voila, you have all of your substrings in a neat vector.  The char is in substrings[0] as a std::string, and the following int values are in substrings[1] and those following, also as std::string.  You will need to convert them to integer values.  For this I suggest you look at stringstream.